# Проблема в jquery DataTables

Tags: jquery

я добавил в один из столбцов таблицы ссылку, на нее "подвешен" обработчик события click. Все работает нормально, но у меня, допустим, 100 записей, разрешено отображаться по 10, когда я с помощью пагинации переключаю на следующие 10, обработчик события click уже не "подвешен" к ссылкам в столбце. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Все, проблема решена, вынес обработчик за пределы обработки события ready, т.е из блока

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   ......
});
```